# RPC_E_SERVERFAULT with IPreviewHandler and Excel files on Dispose

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke, com-interop

I implemented a PreviewHandler control in Winforms/VB.Net using Brad Smith's implementation.

However, whenever my control disposes and the last previewed file was an Excel file, I get an uncatchable ComException with RPC_E_SERVERFAULT when calling IPreviewHandler.Unload(), and I end up with an idle Excel32.exe process (which on top of that hangs my app when I try to preview another Excel file until I manually stop the process).

I found a workaround in a comment of Brad's article, which is to hook to the FormClosing event  of the owner form, and unload the preview handler from there. However, in the comment, the author hooks to the event in the code of the containing form, and not in the control.

The only way I found to hook to the FormClosing event within the control is to hook to the ParentChanged event, and navigate up to the top parent until I find a form, and add the FormClosing handler from there.

However, this does not work in all cases (eg, my PreviewHandler control is nested within another control that is created before the form).

**So is there any way to properly dispose my preview handler control without getting that nasty COMException, or any way to find the parent form from within the control ?**

Dispose code is as follows :

```
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        UnloadPreviewHandler()
    Catch

    End Try

    GC.Collect()

    MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
End Sub

Private Sub UnloadPreviewHandler()
    If previewHandler IsNot Nothing Then
        Try
            ' This line throws the exception when UnloadPreviewHandler is called from Dispose method.
            previewHandler.Unload()
        Finally
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(previewHandler)
            previewHandler = Nothing
        End Try
    End If

    If previewStream IsNot Nothing Then
        previewStream.Close()
        previewStream = Nothing
    End If

    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentTempFile) Then
        Try
            IO.File.Delete(currentTempFile)
        Catch

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT** : As a comment suggested, I tried the C4F implementation (downloaded the kit and ran the PreviewHandlerHost sample). The issue also happens with their implementation (close the app while previewing an Excel or Word file).

Comment: Maybe this will help lukhezo.com/2007/10/10/usercontrol-closing-event/

Comment: Are you manually calling Dispose when this exception occurs?

Comment: @user629926 : Thanks I'll have a look.

Comment: @Nanhydrin : yes and no. Happens in both cases actually.

Comment: Fair enough. Is the unload being called from a different thread or something to where it's created? And just to confirm I understand, if you preview another file that's not excel after the excel file, the Excel executable is shut down correctly?

Comment: @Nanhydrin : For your first question, let me check, I'm not sure. For the second one, that's right. The Excel exec' shuts down properly as soon as I preview another non Excel file.

Comment: And yes, it all happens on the same thread. All I have to do is close the parent form of the control while an Excel file is being previewd to raise the exception. The parallel stack window in VS shows it all happens on the main UI stack.

Comment: Additionally, I just noticed that the same happens with Word, except it does not throw the ComException. It just leaves a Winword.exe process laying around...

Comment: This project also implements same control .You might check their work. c4fdevkit.codeplex.com

Comment: Yes, I already saw it, but their control does no disposal at all... unless I missed something. I'll still give it a try and see if I get the same issue with Excel files.